# jQuery class tabs removing

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is a tabs, the active tab has a red dot and the inactive tab has grey dot but when i click the grey dot it will turn red all dot (remove all inactive class). Why happens this?

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div class="dots">
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <p id="tab1" class="menu">Profile</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dots">
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <p id="tab2" class="menu">The Dic Approach</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dots">
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <p id="tab3" class="menu">The partners</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="tab1C">1Some content</div>
<div class="container" id="tab2C">2Some content</div>
<div class="container" id="tab3C">3Some content</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs .dots .dot:not(:first)").addClass("inactive");
    $('.container').hide();
    $('.container:first').show();
    
    $("#tabs .dots .menu").click(function(){
      var t = $(this).attr("id");
      if($(".dot").hasClass("inactive")){
        $(".dot").addClass("inactive");
        $(".dot").removeClass("inactive");
        
        $(".container").hide();
        $("#" + t + "C").fadeIn("slow");
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: `$(".dot")` is a global selector, not a contextual selector.  It will find, and change, all elements with that selector match.  Thus your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
$(".dot")
```

to

```
$(this).closest(".dots").find(".dot")
```

(or similar) then it will use the dot that matches the currently clicked-on menu

Updated snippet:

```js
    $("#tabs .dots .dot:not(:first)").addClass("inactive");
    $('.container').hide();
    $('.container:first').show();
    
    $("#tabs .dots .menu").click(function(){
      var t = $(this).attr("id");
      var dot = $(this).closest(".dots").find(".dot");
      if (dot.hasClass("inactive")){
        $(".dot").addClass("inactive");
        dot.removeClass("inactive");
        
        $(".container").hide();
        $("#" + t + "C").fadeIn("slow");
      }
    })
```

```css
.dot { color: red; float:left; }
.dot.inactive { color: #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tabs">
    <div class="dots">
      <div class="dot">[.]</div>
      <p id="tab1" class="menu">Profile</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dots">
      <div class="dot">[.]</div>
      <p id="tab2" class="menu">The Dic Approach</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dots">
      <div class="dot">[.]</div>
      <p id="tab3" class="menu">The partners</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="tab1C">1Some content</div>
<div class="container" id="tab2C">2Some content</div>
<div class="container" id="tab3C">3Some content</div>
```

Comment: Or `$(this).siblings(".dot")`, although that depends on them being at the same nesting level.

Comment: @Barmar or `.prev()` yes, lots of different (or similar) options, many of which are brittle (will break if the HTML changes even slightly), not saying that up-down is not brittle, just less-so.

Comment: Sorry, i am new on stackoverflow and forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using global selector like $(".dot") it's get all elements with that (dot) class name